# Wordpress full text without intro text

Tags: wordpress

I need to show the posts of a wordpress site but without the intro text, that is, I want the intro text, the text before the read more, not to show. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking at hiding the intro text in the posts listing, then you will have to edit the post.php page within the theme folder. If you are not into PHP code, then I suggest you look for a theme where the post intro is no shown in the listing.